# How to implement a profit function as metric in keras?

Tags: python, keras

Keras, change metrics for binary classification in sales profit

I have a dataset of sales made by a call center and I want to improve the profit. I think creating a metric that measures the profit will be a good idea. It's a Binary classification, where the profit for each pearson that buys the product is 11 MU and the call cost 3 MU. How can i create this measure in Keras?
If you can provide some code it would be awesome!!

```py
def mean_pred(y_true, y_pred):
    if((y_pred==1) & (y_true == y_pred)):
        return 11
    elif((y_pred==1) & (y_true != y_pred)):
        return -3
    elif((y_pred==0) & (y_true != y_pred)):
        return -8
    return 0

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics=[mean_pred])
```

Maybe this is a loss function? I don't know

Comment: For this to be answerable you would need to tell us how you define profit as function of y_true and y_pred

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro i have already edited it